# Can not install PostgreSQL11. (19.04)

Tags: postgresql, 19.04

Helo everyone.Can anyone help me with this ?
I'm using Ubuntu disco and I did everything as the official PostgreSQL page said when it comes to the repository....

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQqLX.png)

Comment: This is really an error of PostgreSQL packaging. There is no package `libicu60` available on 19.04. You could try `sudo apt install libicu-dev` for which there is a version 60.2.3 available. If that doesn't work, you can take it up with the PostgreSQL developers.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you need version 11? PostgreSQL 10 is available from the Ubuntu repos, and has a much more straightforward way of installing.

Comment: I deleted the repository given by Postgresql and it worked.

Comment: But you didn't install version 11 then? Only 10 is available from the repos, as far as I can tell.